# I need to align the text, so that "current" is on the same line as the rest of the navigation links

Tags: html, css

I need to align my text.
Current it reads in the nav menu:

Home
Visit us Shop Our History

I need  it to be on the same line, and not have home above the rest.

```css
.navigation {
  background-color: #333333;
  Width: 1024px;
  color: #fefefe;
  font-size: 120%;
}

#current {
  border-bottom: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ff0000;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <p>
    <div id="current"> <a href="index.html">Home</a> </div>
    <a href="placeholder.html">Visit Us</a>
    <a href="placeholder.html">Shop</a>
    <a href="placeholder.html">our History</a>
  </p>
</nav>
```

I am SUPER new to this niche.

Comment: You are putting `HOME` in `div` which is block level element . Making it to span in whole line

Comment: I don't see the point of creating such a `div`. Can you put `<a href="index.html" id="current">` so that the id directly refers to the link? (assuming this is what you're doing. (remove the div)

Comment: FWIW the wrapping `p` is also unnecessary.

Comment: ...a div inside a `p` is invalid HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` here

```
.navigation {
  ...
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.navigation {
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 1024px;
  color: #fefefe;
  font-size: 120%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#current {
  border-bottom: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ff0000;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <p>
    <div id="current"> <a href="index.html">Home</a> </div>
    <a href="placeholder.html">Visit Us</a>
    <a href="placeholder.html">Shop</a>
    <a href="placeholder.html">our History</a>
  </p>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an 'inline element' like `<span>` as opposed to a 'block-level element' like `<div>` will fix that.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements#block-level_vs._inline)

```css
.navigation {
  background-color: #333333;
  Width: 1024px;
  color: #fefefe;
  font-size: 120%;
}

#current {
  border-bottom: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ff0000;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <p>
    <span id="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></span>
    <a href="placeholder.html">Visit Us</a>
    <a href="placeholder.html">Shop</a>
    <a href="placeholder.html">our History</a>
  </p>
</nav>
```